# restrict form submission if the hidden input field is empty

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to detect geolocation in the background while submitting the form, please see my code in below

```
<input type="hidden" id="f33" name="f33" value="" data-rule-required="true" readonly  />

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("f33");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.value = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.value = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  " Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

From the above code I'm able to detect the location in the input field, however, the form is still submitting, If the device GPS turned off (As blank field).

Is there any way to restrict the form submission if this input field is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Try marking that field `required`:

```
<form>
  <label for="choose">Would you prefer a banana or cherry?</label>
  <input id="choose" name="i_like" required>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#The_required_attribute

Comment: Thanks for supporting but "required" is not working since the input field is "hidden".

Answer (score 0):

it depends how you submit your form, if you are submiting it via Ajax(javascript) then you can just add if statement. If you are submiting it with html then you could try adding required attribute to input, but that might not be best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic method

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.getElementById("yourFormID").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
    if (document.getElementById("f33").value.trim() === "") {
      alert("Please enable your location services if present");
      e.preventDefault(); // cancel submit
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This is helpful but shows the error but still form is submitting. can you please advice how to restrict the form submitting?

Comment: this looks like it would work. have you changed the value of `yourFormID` ?